# Clearing form two inputs with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

i have a problem with clearing html form inputs. 
This is my situation:

```
<input id="filefield" type="file" name="fileupload"/>            
<textarea id="textareafield" name="textupload"></textarea>

    <script>   
      ('#textareafield').change(function() {
        value1 = $(this).val();
        if (value1 != '') $('#filefield').val('');
    });

      ('#filefield').change(function() {
        value2 = $(this).val();
        if (value2 != '') $('#textareafield').val('');
    });
    </script>
```

If #filefield used delete the content from #textareafield and if #textareafield used delete the content from #filefield. I need a solution with javascript or jquery. Thanks.

Comment: `(...)` just groups an expression. On the code hooking up the change handlers, you probably wanted `$(...)`, which calls the jQuery function referenced by the `$` identifier, just like you have later when looking up the fields to clear their values.

Comment: In web development, one of the key things to do is look in the web console. In this case, it would be showing you the error `Uncaught TypeError: "#textareafield".change is not a function` or similar, pointing to the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    console.log("ready");
    $("#filefield").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $('#textareafield').val('');
          // make this field "readonly"
          $('#textareafield').attr('readonly', true);
        } 
        else {
            $('#textareafield').attr('readonly', false);
        }
   });

   $("#textareafield").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $('#filefield').val('');
          // disable the "file" button
          $('#filefield').attr('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            // enable the "file" button
          $('#filefield').attr('disabled', false);
        }
   });
});
```

Exemple on jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/w3z17dvb/